# Effect of diagonal orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{U_i\}$ be the set of orthogonal matrices that are diagonal. The diagonal elements of any $U_i$ are all therefore $\pm 1$. We also have $1\leq i\leq 2^d$, where $d$ is the dimension of the matrix. Let $\rho$ be any positive semidefinite matrix with unit trace (I'm not sure if these properties are important).

Let $\rho_i = U_i\rho U^{-1}_i$. It is claimed that the average $\rho_i$ over all $i$ is $\rho_D$, the matrix obtained by dropping the off diagonal terms from $\rho$ and only keeping the diagonal entries.

I'm not really sure how to prove this. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't get it. Is $U_i$ a set or a matrix? Or does $U_i$ run over all diagonal orthogonal matrices?

Comment: $U_i$ is one matrix from the set. $i$ goes from 1 to $2^d$, where $d$ is the dimension of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be an orthogonal diagonal matrix and $A$ any matrix. Then the $i,j$-th entry of $UAU^{-1}$ is given by
$$(UAU^{-1})_{ij}=u_{ii}u_{jj}a_{ij}.$$
Hence $i,j$-th entry of the average of all conjugates of $A$ over diagonal orthogonal matrices is
$$\left[\frac{1}{2^d}\sum_{k=1}^{2^d}U_kAU_k^{-1}\right]_{ij}
=\frac{1}{2^d}\sum_{k=1}^{2^d}(U_kAU_k^{-1})_{ij}=\frac{1}{2^d}\sum_{k=1}^{2^d}(u_k)_{ii}(u_k)_{jj}a_{ij},$$
where $(u_k)_{ii}$ denotes the $i$-th diagonal entry of $U_k$. This expression already shows that the diagonal of the average is precisely the diagonal of $A$; if $i=j$ then $(u_k)_{ii}=(u_k)_{jj}$ for all $k$ and hence $(u_k)_{ii}(u_k)_{jj}=1$, so
$$\frac{1}{2^d}\sum_{k=1}^{2^d}(u_k)_{ii}(u_k)_{ii}a_{ii}=\frac{1}{2^d}\sum_{k=1}^{2^d}a_{ii}=a_{ii}.$$
On the other hand, $i\neq j$ then for each $k$ let $V_k$ be the matrix obtained from $U_k$ by changing the sign of the $i$-th diagonal entry. This splits the set of diagonal orthogonal matrices into pairs $(U_k,V_k)$ satisfying
$$(v_k)_{ii}(v_k)_{jj}=-(u_k)_{ii}(u_k)_{jj},$$
from which it follows that
$$\frac{1}{2^d}\sum_{k=1}^{2^d}(u_k)_{ii}(u_k)_{jj}a_{ii}
=\frac{1}{2^d}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{d-1}}((u_k)_{ii}(u_k)_{jj}+(v_k)_{ii}(v_k)_{jj})a_{ij}=0.$$
This shows that the off-diagonal entries of the average are all $0$, which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a rigorous argument but it should help paint the picture of whats going on. First note that $U_i=U_i^{-1}$. Next you can show that right multiplying $\rho$ by $U_i$ simply negates the columns of $\rho$ which correspond to negative diagonal entries of $U_i$, while left multiplying by $U_{i}$ negates the rows of $\rho$ which correspond to negative diagonal entries of $U_i$. E.g. 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
c & -d
\end{pmatrix} 
\quad \quad 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-c & -d
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

This means that conjugating by a $U_i$ whose $k$th diagonal entry is negative negates entries of $\rho$ of the form $\rho_{ik}$ and $\rho_{ki}$ where $i \neq k$. Exactly half of the $U_{i}$ have negative $k$th diagonal entries, so the averaging over the $U_i$ kills off nondiagonal entries.

Also, diagonal entries of $U_i \rho U_i$ are always the same as the diagonal entries of $\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $U_i = U^{T}_{i}=U^{-1}_{i}$, next write the average in index notation:
$<U_{i}^{\alpha\beta}\rho^{\beta \gamma}U_{i}^{\gamma \delta}>$   where $<\cdot>$ denotes the average.

Taking $\rho$ out of the average, we van examine the tensor 
$<U_{i}^{\alpha\beta}U_{i}^{\gamma \delta}>=<\sigma_{i}(\alpha)\sigma_i(\gamma)\delta^{\alpha\beta}\delta^{\gamma \delta}>$  where the $\sigma$ are the $\pm 1$ terms of the diagonals. Unfortunately I used $\delta$ both as an index and as the Kroneker delta, but I believe that there will be no confusion.

At this point we see that the average needs to be performed only on the $\sigma_i$ 
$$<U_{i}^{\alpha\beta}U_{i}^{\gamma \delta}>=<\sigma_{i}(\alpha)\sigma_i(\gamma)>\delta^{\alpha\beta}\delta^{\gamma \delta}$$ and their mean must be zero whenever $\alpha \neq \gamma$ and 1 otherwise, leaving us with 
$$<U_{i}^{\alpha\beta}U_{i}^{\gamma\delta}>=\delta^{\alpha\gamma}\delta^{\alpha\beta}\delta^{\gamma \delta}$$.
plugging back in:
$$<U_{i}^{\alpha\beta}\rho^{\beta \gamma}U_{i}^{\gamma \delta}>=\delta^{\alpha\gamma}\delta^{\alpha\beta}\delta^{\gamma \delta}\rho^{\beta \gamma}=\delta^{\alpha \delta}\rho^{\alpha \delta}$$ as required.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\rho=[a_{ij}], 1\le i,j\le d$.

Since $U_i=U_i^{-1}$, $\rho_i=U_i\rho U_i=U_i[\rho X_1\ \rho X_2\ \rho X_3\ ...\ \rho X_d]$, where $X_1, X_2, ..., X_d$ are the rows/columns of $U_i$.

$=[X_1\ X_2\ X_3\ ...\ X_d]^T[\rho X_1\ \rho X_2\ \rho X_3\ ...\ \rho X_d]$

$=\begin{bmatrix}X_1\rho X_1&X_1\rho X_2&X_1\rho X_3&\ldots&X_1\rho X_d\\X_2\rho X_1&X_2\rho X_2&X_2\rho X_3&\ldots&X_2\rho X_d\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ldots&\vdots\\X_d\rho X_1&X_d\rho X_2&X_d\rho X_3&\ldots&X_d\rho X_d\end{bmatrix}$

It is easily seen why $X_i\rho X_j=(-1)^ma_{ij}$. $X_j$ is all zero except $\pm1$ at the $j^{th}$ position, so $\rho X_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of $\rho$ multiplied by $\pm1$. Pre-multiply by $X_i$ and you have the $i^{th}$ element of the $j^{th}$ column of $\rho$, multiplied by $\pm1$. Also note that $X_j\rho X_j=a_{jj}$ and $X_i\rho X_j$ has the same sign as $X_j\rho X_i$.

$=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&\pm a_{12}&\pm a_{13}&\ldots&\pm a_{1d}\\\pm a_{21}&a_{22}&\pm a_{23}&\ldots&\pm a_{2d}\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ldots&\vdots\\\pm a_{d1}&\pm a_{d2}&\pm a_{d3}&\ldots&a_{dd}\end{bmatrix}$

When you add all $\rho_i$, the sign of $a_{12}$ will be positive for exactly half of $2^d \rho_i$s and negative for the remaining half. This is because the coefficient of $a_{12}$ is given by the product of the first $2$ diagonal entries of $U_i$, and their product is negative $(-1\times1|1\times-1)$ and positive $(1\times1|-1\times-1)$ with equal probability. Similarly for all non-diagonal elements.

Thus, the average, $\displaystyle\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{2^d}\rho_i}{2^d}=\text{diag}[a_{kk}]$